Where is the best place to get bows in TotK?
I have beaten the game and am now working on getting 100%. The most annoying thing is that I keep running out of bows, and rarely find them. Where is a good place to stock up on good bows without using any duplication glitches?

You can easily find several Construct Bows on sky islands. Or, if you have a good setup, you can just kill a random Lynel and grab his Lynel bow (which fires 3+ arrows at the same time).
Another good source of weapons are Shadow Soldiers that are located in the depths, which always have a pristine version of previously broken weapons. Each one will always offer a weapon from a predefined pool (swords, spears and bows), you just have to find the one you need.
(It's also possible to reroll the weapons).

Anyway, the smartest thing to do is never break your weapons, but instead just repair them exploiting Rock Octoroks, which now have the ability to restore durability and add bonuses to your equipment:

When a Rock Octorok swallows a valid piece of Equipment, it will restore both the "base" and "bonus" Durability of the Equipment, as well as the Durability of any Equipment Fused to it. It will also apply a new Weapon Bonus to the base Equipment.

